# Exclude IDs that are tied to a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql

My goal is to return a list of account ids that are tied to only person customers. Some accounts have multiple owners that are person and organizations, and I’m struggling to exclude the accounts tied to both in the result set.

| Account ID | Customer Type |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Person |
| 123 | Organization |
| 4567 | Organization |
| 8910 | Person |

Desired result:

| Account ID | Customer Type |
| --- | --- |
| 8910 | Person |

The table structure is a bit more complex than this so there are a couple joins to get both account and customer type in the same result set. I’ve tried a couple of different things like NOT IN a subquery, != ‘Organization’, and a couple of other things.

Does anyone have suggestions? TIA

```
SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM ACCOUNT A
JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE A.ACCOUNT_ID NOT IN (SELECT A.ACCOUNT_ID, C.CUSTOMER_TYPE
FROM ACCOUNT A
JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = A.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE C.CUSTOMER_TYPE != ‘ORGANIZATION’)
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If the tables you have shown have the sample data, this will do: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ee_28LMF. If not, you should improve your question and show the real tables with their sample data rather than a query result.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 solutions

1.you can use a NOT EXISTS clause along with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.account_id
FROM account a
JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_type = 'Person'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM customer c2 
  WHERE c2.customer_id = a.customer_id
  AND c2.customer_type = 'Organization'
)
```

2.use GROUP BY and HAVING:

```
SELECT a.account_id
FROM account a
JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id  
GROUP BY a.account_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.customer_type = 'Organization' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```